# How to fix "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Tags: python, pandas, dask, rdkit

so I searched a lot and maybe I'm just not experienced enough with programming to figure my issue out by myself.
I'm working on a big dataset with Python/Dask/RDKit to compute some Chemoinformatics-Stuff(Descriptors etc.). Therefore I created a dataframe of my .csv and do aforementioned computations on each row. The .csv file contains only one column with my molecules (SMILES) and I want to add further columns with the descriptors, for this (first) example the molecular weight. But in the end I receive a ValueError: "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" and I must admit I don't know what this is supposed to mean, less how to fix it. I'll add the code below and would be very very greatful, if someone could at least give me a hint in the right direction.
Cheers
Philipp

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from rdkit.Chem.Descriptors import MolWt
from rdkit import Chem
import time

def calc_mw(smi):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi)
    if mol != None:
        return MolWt(mol)
    else:
        return None
    
    
def mw_df(df):
    return df.Smiles.apply(calc_mw)

def main():
    start = time.time()
    df = dd.read_csv("file.csv", blocksize=16*1024*1024)
    df["MWT"]= df.map_partitions(mw_df,meta='float').compute(scheduler='processes')
    print(time.time()-start)
    print(df.head())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: My guess is that because you have read a csv in blocks, that the index is not known thus cannot be used to join a new column. If your csv comes without an index you can just add `df = df.reset_index().set_index('index')`. Maybe this will work

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried the resetting of the indexor even dropping the blocksize argument, but neither did work.

Comment: Maybe that helps someone with my problem: My file has 54,864,237 lines and no index in the file. The last row from df.tail() with using Pandas is that exact same count. But when I use df.tail() with the Dask dataframe , the index for the last entry is 134,356.  But resetting the index or dropping the blocksize argument didn't work here either.